# Should I be deleting local pointers that point to static

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

As the question title implies, if I have some static constant. Let's say a large number of static arrays and I need to determine which static array to use I can do so by checking some conditions and returning a pointer to the static array that is needed.

However, if I store `(type) * (name) = (static array)` in some function do I need to call `delete` on this?

Comment: No, calling `delete` on any pointer that has not been allocated with `new`, or even mixing up `delete[]` and `delete`, would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "static array" you mean you declared `static int x[100];` somewhere, and your function is returning a pointer to the first element of `x` (e.g. function `int *foo` ends with `return x;`, and you do `int *bar = foo();`), no, you definitely don't want to `delete` that pointer; it wasn't allocated from the heap with `new`, so it must not be `delete`d; `delete` only deals with heap memory.

Answer (score 0):

`delete` would be necessary if, and only if, the target memory was allocated by `new`.